# Apart from + infinitive

Tags: infinitives, prepositional-phrases, ing

A [piece of news from the BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/language/wordsinthenews/2013/05/130510_witn_haiti_cholera.shtml) reads as follows [emphasis in the original]:

> The UN has said very little on the matter, apart from **to insist** it
>   is immune from legal proceedings.

Now, I knew that any prepositional phrase must be followed by the -*ing* form of the verb, so I’d have expected the reporter to use “insisting”. Is it a correct usage? If it is, are there any other prepositional phrases that can be followed by the infinitive form?

Comment: I think a clever newsreader might manage to get through this without gagging or correcting on the fly, but I can't. You're entirely correct; this is ungrammatical, and the infinitive is the reason.

Comment: I agree with John Lawler.  Keeping the infinitive, the reader could have said, "The UN have said very little on the matter.  They did, however, continue to insist they are immune from legal proceedings." (We yanks would say, "The UN has said . . ..  It did, however, continue to insist it . . ..").  Actually, I kind of prefer the British version!

Comment: What startles me is that the reporter _read_ and _recorded_ a text he had prepared before. Didn’t he realize that he had made such a howler?

Comment: @rhetorician I'm a Brit, and I would have said "The UN *has* said ...". (I don't like the implication that I might be using an Americanism!! ;-) )

Comment: @TrevorD:  No need to allow your hackles to be raised (I assume--perhaps incorrectly--you've taken at least mild umbrage at my implication).  There was no offense intended on my part.  Why don't all we English speakers agree on using some sort of punctuation (besides exclamation points) to indicate we have our tongues planted firmly in our cheeks.  Your use of two !!s was a bit of a question mark (pun intended) to me.  What happened to the interrobang? Do Brits still say, for example, "The Chrysler Corporation have moved their headquarters to Timbukto?"

Comment: @rhetorician Sorry, my reply obviously came over much more strongly than intended - I meant it to be slightly jovial. I was just replying to your comment that, as a Brit, I don't use what you called "the British version" & *jokingly* that I didn't want to be seen using something that might be considered an Americanism. I certainly didn't type any exclamation marks at the end - whether you mis-read them or whether they are somehow displayed differently? It was intended to be *semi-colon + dash + bracket* to show a 'winking' smiley face, followed by a second bracket to end the parenthesis.

Comment: @rhetorician ... ran out of allowed number of characters. As regards you final question, I don't know which is more common, but I think that either of *have moved their* and *has moved its* might been seen.  Personally, I *think* I would use the singular - but then in an unguarded moment I might use the plural.

Comment: @TrevorD:  Thanks for your reply.  As to how your punctuation appears in your posting, this is what I see:  !!;-)).  I squinted really hard to see a smiley face, to no avail.  I still think the interrobang is a good idea.  Come to think of it, however, ironic, sarcastic, and sardonic communications have so many shades and nuances that we should probably have a different punctuation mark for each mode:  the ironobang, the  sarcobang, and the sardonibang?  We could use the initial letter of the Greek word for each mode.  What thinkest thou?

Comment: To make matters worse, I just came across the following on a manual that supposedly teaches English..."We did nothing apart from LIE on the beach", and it gives such sentence as AN EXAMPLE sentence for the complex preposition APART FROM. Ouch!

Comment: Speaking "to insist something" has a subtly different meaning from speaking "insisting something": with "to", you're referring to purpose, with "ing" you're providing a description. It's certainly grammatical to say "he spoke to insist that he was innocent" and "he spoke for many reasons, for example to insist his innocence".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object of a prepositional phrase is almost always a noun or functions as a noun (e.g. a gerund).  You can see, then that the prepositional phrase `from to insist...` breaks this rule of thumb.  `From insisting...` would be better.

Comment: Thanks. To your knowledge, is it a common mistake or just an occasional one?

Comment: You might occasionally see this in some complex constructions, but in general this type of prepositional phrase would be edited to a more pleasing form in any formal text.